# React Native, how to change the BottomborderColor of a TextInputField when selected?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I wanna create a SignIn Screen where the Color of the bottomBorder from the TextInput changes when the user select it and start typing  to the Color '#FFCC00'. Can someone help me with that Question and tell me what to add to my Code? It would be also nice when someone can leave a link how to connect and Setup a complete authentication System. That would be really nice because i found Nothing that works :(

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  selectionColor,
} from 'react-native';

class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#2D6097',
      title: 'Sign In',
    };
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#fff" barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Text style={styles.login}>Regsitrieren</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-Mail"
          onChangeText={this.handleEmail}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Username"
          onChangeText={this.username}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={this.password}
        />
        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.userBtn}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp2')}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>SignUp</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  login: {
    fontSize: 40,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    color: '#555',
    borderBottomColor: '#2D6097',
    borderBottomWidth: 3,
  },
  input: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 50,
    borderBottomColor: '#2D6097',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 25,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  userBtn: {
    backgroundColor: '#2D6097',
    padding: 10,
    margin: 20,
    marginBottom: 50,
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: '80%',
  },
  btnText: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff',
  },
});

export default SignUpScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onFocus` in TextInput is called when the TextInput is focused & conditionally render your style according to that. Also make sure to change `isFocusEmail` value when TextInput is not focused using `onBlur`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class SignUpScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    isFocusEmail: false
  };

  handleInFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocusEmail: true });

  handleOutFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocusEmail: false });

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.login}>Regsitrieren</Text>
        <TextInput
          onFocus={this.handleInFocus}
          onBlur={this.handleOutFocus}
          style={
            this.state.isFocusEmail
              ? [styles.input, { borderBottomColor: "#FFCC00" }]
              : styles.input
          }
          placeholder="E-Mail"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  login: {
    fontSize: 40,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 50,
    color: "#555",
    borderBottomColor: "#2D6097",
    borderBottomWidth: 3
  },
  input: {
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 50,
    borderBottomColor: "#2D6097",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    fontSize: 25
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: You can also do `style={[ styles.input, this.state.isFocusEmail && { borderBottomColor: "#FFCC00" }  ]}`